# SharePoint 2013 - Hiding a View from the View Dropdown

Tags: 2013, view, dropdown

I've created multiple views for each individual working on a specific project. They will be using their unique view to view their assigned tasks. I wanted to hide the unique views from the dropdown when looking at the list. The views aren't confidential or anything, just having so many views in that dropdown can be a clutter.

I want to hide the new unique views JUST from the dropdown. I want each employee to still have access to other unique views from the list settings page or from the specific URL. This isn't a permissions issue, just a cosmetic request.

[image: Example image]

In the photo above, I want to hide the views in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the whole menu before rendering with CSR (Client Side Rendering)

Use the WYSiWYG [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo) to replace the script:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
        Header: function (ctx, columns) {
          var views = JSON.parse(ctx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
          //display all View options except 'Create View' & 'Modify View'
          ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = views.length; 

         views = views.filter(function (view) {
            console.log(view.DisplayText, view);
            var isMenu=view.MenuOptionType===2;
            return isMenu || view.DisplayText.indexOf('View') <0; // false will not be returned
          });

          ctx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions = JSON.stringify(views);//create string defintion again
          return RenderHeaderTemplate(ctx, columns); //render default Header template
        }
      }
    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/hideview.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

This will delete(array.filter) all Views that not have the string 'View' in the DisplayText

Also note the option to list all Views (not just the 3 default)

You can also add View references, see the console fr the exact required syntax

iCSR iJS iView